# HttpClient does not work with dev certifcate

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient

I want to use `HttpClient` to make requests using a certificate.

I generated a dev certificate using the following command

`dotnet dev-certs https -ep dev_cert.pfx -p 1234`

So I created an API to use that certificate. Here is the implementation.

```
public static class AuthenticationExtension
{
    public static void ConfigureAuthetication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate(options =>
            {
                var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\dev_cert.pfx", "1234");
                options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                options.ChainTrustValidationMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
                options.CustomTrustStore = new X509Certificate2Collection { cert };
                options.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
                options.ValidateCertificateUse = false;
                options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ClientCertificateValidationService>();
                        if (validationService != null && validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Success");
                            context.Success();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("invalid cert");
                            context.Fail("invalid cert");
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnChallenge = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
    }
}
```

I added the `Authorize` attribute in the controller method

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
[Authorize]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

I tested the request using Postman and it worked as expected.

Then, I created a console app to make the request using `HttpClient`. It failed always with the Forbidden Status code.

So I tested using the obsolete `WebRequest`. And It worked as expected.

Here is the implementation for that

```
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;


var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certificates.Import(@"D:\dev_cert.pfx", "1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
handler.ClientCertificates.AddRange(certificates);

using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7148/");


try
{
    var response = await client.GetAsync("weatherforecast/");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Failed  {response.StatusCode}");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Failed  {ex}");
}

string host = @"https://localhost:7148/weatherforecast";

try
{

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    req.ClientCertificates = certificates;
    req.Method = "GET";

    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();

    Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    stream.Close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

My question is... Since the `WebRequest` is obsolete what I can do to make the `HttpClient` work?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Based on my testing, both httpclient and the webrequest will all not work from your codes. They return the same error. Could you please tell me how you configure your application's certficiate? Did you use the Dev or the localhost as the website certficate?

Comment: I used the `dotnet dev-certs https -ep dev_cert.pfx -p 1234 ` command to generate the certificate. And I know the webrequest is working.

Comment: Could you please post your program.cs codes?